# Too Many Constants error

Tags: java, soap, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I am trying to generate java code from wsdl using axis2-1.6.2. I have a very big `WSDL` file. When I generate java code I got an error in `ExtensionMapper` class. Error is as follow :-

> Too many constants, the constant pool for ExtensionMapper would exceed 65536 entries

As I searched over web, I know maximum entries could be `65536` entries only. As I have to use this WSDL, is there any way to generate code without above error ?

**Note :-** I am using eclipse to generate java code with default settings.

Comment: woow.  you did it boy

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ : What have I done ?

Comment: Can't you split the `WSDL`?

Comment: @RobAu :- No, it is just 31kb with 41 XSD files. As per the provider terms We have to use this service as it is without any change.